# I downloaded some kitbash assets to use in my mech project but for some reason they look dark grey and there are no materials in that object either

Tags: materials, objects, import

I downloaded some kitbash assets to use in my mech project but for some reason they look dark grey and there are no materials in that object either. The problem is it looks darker no matter what I do, even when I remove materials they are still darker. If I add a new material the material becomes darker too.

[image: This is a render image and they don't have any material except that black one]